# Why Laravel Not Using Models

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

I am an experienced Laravel for the past two years.Before Laravel I used the CodeIgnitor and switched to Laravel.

In Laravel my Code to get the table data is like.

```
 $customers = DB::table('customers')->get();
```

Here I can get all the data as expected and working great.

But the flow of Laravel like as I learned is,

1. When User accessing **about-us** page, the routes.php searching the route and call the corresponding Controller and function.

   ```
   Route::get('about-us',['as'=>'about_us','uses'=>'IndexController@aboutUs']);
   ```
2. When reached on IndexController the function is doing databse operations and returning the View.

   ```
   public function aboutUs(){
      $customers = DB::table('customers')->get();
      return View::make('about-us')
        ->with('customers',$customers);
   }
   ```
3. The View is just doing the foreach statement for echoing the customers.

   ```
   @foreach($customers as $customer)
      <h1>{{$customer->customer_name}}</h1>
   @endforeach
   ```

In this Scenario, Where is the use of Model is working ?

The Model is not using in this Method ?

This is the Proper method for making a coding standard ?

Is Laravel surely following the MVC Structure ?

Comment: No. This is not proper coding standard. You can use `laravel's eloqunent` modal function from controller and  write queries at there

Comment: Don't you think that `DB::table('customers')` refers to `customers` model?

Comment: @u_mulder, but I dont make any model for customers for running this query ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the Eloquent way to get data out of the database:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries

This is the way for Models:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent

I can give you more information, but the documentation is really good!

Query:
    $customers = DB::table('customers')->get();

Model:
    $customers = Customers::all();

In the model, Customers is a new class where you can define the table name etc.
All the properties are dynamic.

There is also another alternative: http://www.laraveldoctrine.org/docs/1.1/orm

Comment: I dont need any links for this question as answer,Just tell me this method is proper and if not why its not proper ?

Comment: It's not that proper. When you have custom methods you can declare them in the Model Class. And when you have relationships you can do the following: $articles = $customer->articles 

But there are also Mutators and accessors for your properties.
But everything is in the documentation. 

At this moment, all your logic will be in your controllers.

Comment: The what are difference between Models and plains ?

Comment: You can do everything plain, but what if your table name change? Are you going to every file and change the table name?

Comment: But if you use the Customers table only for that purpose, it's okay.

Comment: Exactly, That is a good difference... but why Laravel encourage plain

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112648/discussion-between-jishad-p-and-demian).

Comment: When you update a model, or create one, the created_at and updated_at timestamps will automatically be set.

Also when you modify, the updated_at will be automatically be set.
When you delete a model, you can use soft delete.
Then the model gets a deleted_at timestamp, and it isn't deleted !
But when you do Customers::all() , that model won't be listed